# My code's output is not the array I input

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to run the following code in order to input an array of any size I desire:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class testing2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double[] inputs = new double[5];
        int currentSize = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Please enter values, Q to quit:");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while (in.hasNextDouble())
        { 
           if (currentSize >= inputs.length)
           {
              inputs = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, 2 * inputs.length);
           }
          
           inputs[currentSize] = in.nextDouble();
           currentSize++;
        }
        inputs = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, currentSize);
        
        System.out.print(inputs);

    }

}
```

But when I input any array, my output is just a combination of symbols such as: *[D@13fee20c*, and this is not the output I am hoping for. Could anyone help me?

Comment: [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing correctly:

```java
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
            System.out.print(input[i] + " ");
    }
```